# Windows Phone Browser Control Execute JS function to replace src attribute

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8

I am working on a Windows Phone app that utilizes a WebBrowser control to view HTML content.  I am using the browser.NavigateToString() method to view the HTML.  I have a case where the HTML I receive has a bogus src attribute (src="cid:XXXX") and in my app I need to manually download the image from a separate location.

I am attempting to create a JavaScript function that will allow me to update the src attribute of the image after I download it.  I tested out the JS on Firefox and it seems to work ok, but when I call it via the InvokeScript() method it fails to update the image source.

Here is the JS method:

```
function updateElementAttribute(tagName, attributeValue, replacementValue) 
{
    var i, n, elements=document.getElementsByTagName(tagName), len=elements.length;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) 
    {
         n = elements[i].src;
         if (n && (n == attributeValue)) 
         {                            
               document.getElementsByTagName(tagName)[i].src = replacementValue; 
         }
     }
}
```

Then I call the JS function on the browser via:

```
string[] args = new string[] { "img", cid, uri };
browser.InvokeScript("updateElementAttribute", args);
```

Any ideas on why the img field is not updating.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like after restarting Visual Studio and reloading my app, it seems be working correctly now...